# Possible to disable LG Cliptray?

Tags: lg, lg-g2

My LG G2 (and I assume other LG phones) have a "Cliptray" which replaces the clipboard with one where you can access the history. I'd like to remove this function as 1Password cannot remove copied passwords after a set time.

Phone is rooted, if that helps.

Comment: I can't find an answer anywhere. The only suggestions I can give are to either call LG themselves and ask (it is a horrible security hole in their system IMHO) or go into your system apps and see if there is something with a name like Clip Tray or such. Be wary of deleting it rather than freezing it, and of course disabling this **could** have unforseen consequences. Alternatively a custom ROM could be used without this feature in the first place.

Comment: The LG G3 also has this. Before I flashed CM12, I looked to see how to disable this. I could not find any settings to turn it off, and the "app" itself could not be found either. It seems that LG put this in as part of their Core OS, so there isn't a specific app to disable. It is part of the Core OS because it shows up everywhere, and in conjunction with the "copy/paste" system menus.

Answer (score 2):

Since the device is rooted, here's a way of disabling Clip Tray:

1. Go into Clip Tray and delete all entries.
2. In the file `/system/etc/permissions/com.lge.software.cliptray.xml`, change this line

   ```
   &lt;feature name="com.lge.software.cliptray"/&gt;
   ```

   to

   ```
   &lt;!-- &lt;feature name="com.lge.software.cliptray"/&gt; --&gt;
   ```

   This will put the feature in *comment*, and will not grant permission for this feature.
3. Reboot the device.

**Note**: You might still see the option *Paste, Cliptray* in your stock LG keyboard, which will not work after this modification but cannot be hidden or removed. A way to work around that is to use an alternate keyboard, like [Google Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin).

Answer (score 0):

Please update to the latest version of the o/s now they have added this functionality...
To enable automatic clipboard clearing, go to Settings > Security > Automatically clear clipboard and tap on the the time interval that you would like. Like for example 30 sec and after 30 sec your clipboard will be emptied.
I hope that this helps!

Comment: It doesn't remove the entries stored in the Clip Tray history, only what's in the clipboard at this moment.

Answer (score -1):

With that permission edit, it affects how the screenshots are saved. 
You get a warning toast about the file not saving, and then the "saving screenshot" notification, never goes away, until you reset your phone.
The screenshot does actually save though.

Edit:

You can avoid this side effect by instead running this command ([source](https://www.reddit.com/r/lgg4/comments/3ywx84/psa_how_to_disable_clip_tray_requires_root_or_twrp/cyig5lt)):

```
rm /data/data/com.lge.systemservice/databases/clipdata.db && ln -s /dev/null /data/data/com.lge.systemservice/databases/clipdata.db
```

Or

Select option B from this app, which enters the command for you: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jfsoftware.disablecliptray